# PHP String date + 1 workdays

Tags: php

I have date

```
$date = '2018-04-20'
//Format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

How i can get string + **1 WORKDAYS** like

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime("$date + 1 days"));
```

so the result is **'2018-04-23'** not '2018-04-21' because it's saturday

note : workdays is monday till friday

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try like this for weekdays,

```
<?php
 $date = '2018-04-20';
 echo date ( 'Y-m-d' , strtotime ( $date. ' +1 weekdays' ) );
?>
```

**Program Output**

```
2018-04-23
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/979016